How can I create a WPF application which scales according to window height and is not affected by system dpi scaling?
I'm creating an industrial process monitoring and control application in C# using WPF for the UI. This application runs full-screen and will be deployed on a variety of windows computers which have different resolutions (1024x768, 1920x1080, and 1920x1200) and dpi scaling settings (100%, 125%, and 150%). I've been thinking about how I want to approach this problem and so far I've decided on this:
I design the whole ui for 1024x768, I design the layout to have flexible width in certain areas, and I scale everything according to height, ignoring the system dpi scaling.
Viewboxes don't seem to work because they destroy the layout completely. I'm also not sure I need to even combat the system dpi settings because I might naturally get the same effect when scaling by height if the height itself is measured in device-independent pixels.
Also, is there a better approach to what I'm trying to accomplish? There's a fixed amount of information I need to display on the screen regardless of resolution or scaling. Creating different layouts depending on the screen's aspect ratio would be very cool, but that may be too complex for now.

"Viewboxes ... destroy the layout completely." - then you must have done something completely wrong.

I don't think so. Viewboxes will render scrollviews useless by giving the contents as much space as they need. The only way I know to combat this is by specifying heights and widths of things. But then the contents of the viewbox will be locked into a certain aspect ratio. Maybe I'm wrong, but I really don't think viewboxes will work here.

That is not true. You would obviously assign a fixed Height and perhaps also a fixed Width to the Viewbox child.

I set a fixed height and set horizontal alignment to stretch on the child of the viewbox, but the child doesn't want to stretch and fill the width of the window. I can't assign a fixed width because that will lock me into a certain aspect ratio.

You may use a Viewbox with a child element with a fixed Height. Then determine the aspect ratio in a SizeChanged event handler and set the child's Width appropriately.
<Grid SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid x:Name="scaledGrid" Height="768" Background="AliceBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello, World"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>

The event handler:
private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var aspectRatio = e.NewSize.Width / e.NewSize.Height;

    scaledGrid.Width = scaledGrid.ActualHeight * aspectRatio;
}


Ok this works perfectly. Although it bothers me a bit that when the viewbox is the root element, it doesn't seem to work. I just substituted the root grid for a contentcontrol. Also very neat that, like i suspected with this sort of technique, there is no need to combat the dpi scaling. Although do you think there may be some sort of performance hit when dpi scaling is not at 100%? Because the rendering system is transforming for the dpi scaling, then doing another transform to fit the contents in the viewbox. Or perhaps the scaling for both is multiplied and there is only one render.

There is no performance penalty at all. WPF is vector graphics that is freely scalable. Whether you combine a few scaling factors or not makes no difference.

That's very cool. Do you know why it doesn't work when the viewbox is the root element in the window? The viewbox or maybe its contents aren't using the full width. Simply moving the viewbox into a contentcontrol and moving the sizechanged event to the contentcontrol makes it work.

The Window size includes the sizes of the border and title bar. So you don't get the exact aspect ratio of the client area.

I understand that. But try removing the outermost grid and move the sizechanged event to the viewbox. The viewbox is now very narrow. Nowhere close to filling the width of the window.

Sure, that is why there is the top-level Grid. It is unclear what exactly your problem is with this fact. This is just how a Viewbox works. Btw, using a ContentControl doesn't make much sense, as it is meant to apply a DataTemplate to visualize its Content. The most simple element to host a single child is a Border.

It just feels strange. That's all. Also, I am using the ContentControl to apply a DataTemplate and is how I'm handling navigation in my application. If you're referring to my answer, I just put text in there to simplify the example.

I am of course talking about the outer ContentControl. The type of the inner control is totally irrelevant in the context of your question.

Right. I ended up using your solution, but I replaced the top-level grid with a Decorator. Would a Decorator be the most primitive element to use? I know it doesn't really matter in practice, but I'm curious.

If you have such a big problem with the outer Panel, you could certainly create a derived Viewbox that overrides the layout methods to stretch in only one of the two directions. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4543983/1136211

I don't have a huge problem with it. I just didn't understand why it was necessary and it felt strange. And I do like that in your solution, the base height is defined in the xaml instead of the codebehind.

And while we're at it: what do you think of this approach of scaling the whole ui based on height? Keep in mind the ui is basically a human-machine interface and there is a fixed amount of information I need to display. The only thing better I can think of is creating different layouts depending on the aspect ratio, but I'm not sure if that's necessary yet. So far, I have numerical readouts (which have a fixed aspect ratio) laid out on the left side of the screen, and the right side of the screen has real-time charts which will grow to take up the remainder of the screen's width.

I wouldn't do any manual scaling at all. There would be a Grid with two columns. The numerical readouts would be arranged in a vertical StackPanel in the left column (with Width=Auto) and the charts would fill the right column (with Width=*). The application would of course also be DPI-aware to deal with different screen resolutions.

But there are problems with that approach for this application. For examle: Two computers which are 1920x1080, but the system dpi scaling is set to 100% on one, and 150% on the other. That would make the application look different when they should look the same. Another example: Two computers with the same dpi scaling settings, but one computer is 1920x1080 and the other is 1366x768 (same aspect ratio). Again, the application would look different.

Honestly, that doesn't make sense. If you have two screens with similar resolution and size, they should have the same DPI scaling. If you have a third screen with that size, but higher resolution it should have a higher DPI scaling. The whole idea of DPI scaling is to replace physical pixel density by logical pixel density, which should be similar on all devices.

If this is actually an "industrial process monitoring and control application" the system administrators or service technicians should simply set an appropriate scaling.

Most simple element to host single child really is Grid. WPF authors didn't see a point in creating special Panel to host single child, because Grid without Column/RowDefinition does exactly that. Border/Decorator/ContentControl are all templated controls, which means they visual tree does not match logical tree. Panels (e.g. Grid) does not manilupate visual tree, they just arrage children. Get used to it.

@Liero, Good info. Thanks.

@Clemens, "If you have two screens with similar resolution and size, they should have the same DPI scaling.": They don't. "... the system administrators or service technicians should simply set an appropriate scaling.": There is practically no system administrator once the computer is in the field. And the technicians don't know what the appropriate scaling is. And I have no control over most of these computers. These are mobile operations. Our situation is not ideal.
